# urllib.Request remove Content-Type header

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, post

I want to remove the content-type header from a POST request. I have tried setting the header to `''`

```
try:
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
test_data = 'test'

req = Request(url, test_data.encode(), headers={'Content-Type': ''})
req.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
print(urlopen(req).read().decode())
```

But this sends:

```
{
  // ...
  "headers": {
     "Content-Type": "", // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

What I would like it to do is send no Content-Type at all, instead of a blank one. By default, it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

This can easily be acheived with `requests`:

```
print(requests.post(url, test_data).text)
```

But this is a script I need to distribute, so cannot have dependencies. I need it to have no Content-Type at all, since the server is very picky, so I cannot use `text/plain` or `application/octet-stream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify custom handler:

```
try:
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen, build_opener, BaseHandler
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, build_opener, BaseHandler

url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
test_data = 'test'

class ContentTypeRemover(BaseHandler):
    def http_request(self, req):
        if req.has_header('Content-type'):
            req.remove_header('Content-type')
        return req
    https_request = http_request

opener = build_opener(ContentTypeRemover())
req = Request(url, test_data.encode())
print(opener.open(req).read().decode())
```

---

Another (hacky) way: monkey-patching the request object to pretend there's `Content-type` header already there; prevents `AbstractHTTPHandler` to default Content-Type header.

```
req = Request(url, test_data.encode())
req.has_header = lambda header_name: (header_name == 'Content-type' or
                                      Request.has_header(req, header_name))
print(urlopen(req).read().decode())
```

Comment: The first method only seems to work in Python 3, as Python 2 has no `req.remove_header` method. The second method works in both, and can be made less hacky by making a subclass. I can also make it POST with a subclass too. Thanks!

Comment: @Artyer, It's hacky because it's not documented and depends on implementation details.

Comment: @Artyer, In Python 2.x, `req.headers.pop('Content-type', None)` and `req.unredirected_hdrs.pop('Content-type', None)` instead of `req.remove_header(..)`.

Comment: The body in that `lambda` could be rewritten as `header_name == 'Content-type' or Request.has_header(req, header_name)`. Note that evaluation of that expression will stop at the `or` if the first part already evaluates to `True`

Comment: @UlFie, You're right. Thank you for the comment. I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add ontop of @falsetru's answer,

If you need to filter more headers than this, `req.headers` is not the thing you want, it's more like this:

```py
class ContentTypeRemover(BaseHandler):
    def __init__(self, headers_to_filter={'Content-type'}): # set or dict works
        self.headers_to_filter = headers_to_filter

    def http_request(self, req):
        for header, value in req.header_items():
            if header in self.headers_to_filter:
                req.remove_header(header)
        return req
    https_request = http_request
```

And if you need to modify a header, not remove it.. It gets a bit weird (at least this is the only method I've found to be working):

```py
req.remove_header(header)
req.add_header(header, self.modify_headers[header.lower()])
```